# $in for multiple values

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
var footballerIdToPassive = "qqqqq";
var footballerlevelToPassive = ["3052002","3052003"];

db.goals.find({ "footballer": footballerIdToPassive, "footballerlevel": { $in: [footballerlevelToPassive]}}))
```

for that it brings nothing but in goals db shell, when i run count of this, count is 1

```
{ "footballer": "qqqqq", "footballerlevel": "3052002" }
```

also for

```
var footballerlevelToPassive = "3052002";
```

this, it works. but i cant do for multiple. HOw can i do this work?

i need to use each , i need to update each one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`footballerlevelToPassive`  is already an array, there's no need to wrap it in another array again in your query, just reference it directly with `$in` as

```
var footballerIdToPassive = "qqqqq";
var footballerlevelToPassive = ["3052002","3052003"];

db.goals.find({ 
    "footballer": footballerIdToPassive, 
    "footballerlevel": { "$in": footballerlevelToPassive }
})
```

which is equivalent to the query

```
db.goals.find({ 
    "footballer": footballerIdToPassive, 
    "$or": [
        { "footballerlevel": "3052002" },
        { "footballerlevel": "3052003" }
    ]
})
```

**Quick demo**

[image]